# run linux command using execlp with more than one argument as string in c

Tags: c, linux, operating-system, system-calls

I am trying to run `ls` using system calls in C with more than one argument, for example -l -a. The arguments and their number is changing depending on the user input. The input is concatenated "-l" + "-a" == "-l -a". The code I'm using is:

```
execlp("ls","ls",arguments,NULL) //arguments = "-l -a"
```

The user input is from Terminal:

```
-l
-a
```

Comment: The arguments needs to be passed one by one. Otherwise it's interpreted as a *single* argument. So if the `arguments` string is some kind of input, then you need to split it up. And it's not going to be possible (really) to use `execlp`, instead use [`execvp`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/execvp.3.html) where you pass an *array* of strings (terminated by a null pointer).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I think you could post that as an answer because using `execvp` is exactly the right solution.

Comment: BTW, `NULL` is wrong there, it *must* be `(char *)NULL`. (Even the Linux man pages spell this out).

Comment: @AnttiHaapala what's the difference between (char *)NULL and NULLL

Comment: @KarinaK `(char *)NULL` is an expression of type `char *`, `NULL` is an expression of implementation-defined type that no one can tell how it works in a varargs function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to executes more than one argument , then you should use `execvp()` instead of `execlp`.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{

        execvp(argv[1],argv+1);// argv+1 means whatever arguments after argv[1] it will take & executes it 
        return 0;
}
```

for e.g your input like that

```
xyz@xyz-PC:~$ ./a.out ps -el
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: execvp(argv[2],argv+1); 
here argv[2] is ls as argv and argv+1 is -l but i dont get any output to the terminal. I start from argv[2] because argv[1] is for another side of the program

Comment: @KarinaK then what you are giving for argv[1] ?

Comment: For a counter in a previous part of the program.  for example the input is ./a.out used_argument ls -l

Comment: okay,  then you can use like you suggested, but first you need to do increment argv. Do you want to execute both "used_arguement" and "ls -l?

Comment: @KarinaK  have you got ? what is "used_argument", Is it another argument of "ls" ?

Comment: No, it's not, it's for a previous part of the program. The answer worked though.